# Multiple user types login

Tags: ruby, polymorphic-associations

I am a new Ruby user, and have searched the forums, and although there are similiar questions posted, I was unable to fully relate.  Hence, my question.

I have a site that has 2 different types of users with different and shared attributes (Shoppers & Stores) Both should be able to login, but will have different functionality and navbar options throughout the site.  They will also share some functionality.  For example, both should be able to search data in the stores.  However, only Stores will be able to update the data within them.

I originally created a user class with email, encrypted_password, salt, etc..  I wanted to leverage the signup / login code.  But each type of user will additionally have functionality.

I thought of having the following database:

```
create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :encrypted_password
      t.string :salt
      t.timestamps
end

create_table :shoppers do |t|
  t.integer  :dollars 
  t.string   :promo_info
end  

create_table :stores do |t|
  t.string   :address
  t.string   :city
  t.string   :zipcode
  t.string   :category_id
end
```

Then I would have a Shopper & Store class that would inherit from the User class, gaining all the login / signup functionality defined there.  Or would it make more sense to simply have each Store & Shopper have a User, and delegate the any authentication calls to it shopper.user.login()

Am I thinking about this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're thinking about this correctly imho.

This is really an OOD question: you're asking whether to use composition (the Store class *has a* User) or inheritenace (the Store class *is a* User). Composition is widely considered a better design choice. I suggest you google [composition vs inheritance](http://www.google.com/search?q=composition%20vs%20inheritance) for more information.

In your case I believe that composition makes more sense. The authentication functionality that's implemented by the User class isn't directly related to the functionality implemented by either Store or Shopper. Moreover, a Store could logically have more than one User: multiple employees of the store, possibly with different authorization levels, accessing your system.

Comment: Background: I am by experience a java developer, although have been out of practice for a couple years.  I have read the article, and tend to agree (composition).   

However, not following why it is an odd question though, and how should I be thinking about it.   I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: I wrote OOD (as in Object Oriented Design), not odd ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you really want for this is Single Table Inheritance. You don't need any polymorphic associations, either.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class Store < User; end
class Shopper < User; end
```

Implement user-related methods and validations in User and Store/Shopper–specific logic in the respective subclass.

Your controllers and views are another deal altogether. You will probably want to namespace "stores" and maintain a separate set of controllers and views within that namespace for all of the special views and functionality that stores will have (and shoppers won't). Then the default case (and routes/paths) are for shoppers.

```
resources :products, :only => [:index, :show]

namespace :shoppers do
  resources :products
end
```

Run `rake routes` and you'll see what you get out of that.